# Copy comments that are after the end of root tag using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an XML which needs to be reordered and stored in another file. I have done an xslt for that and it works fine. 
However if there are comments after the xml ends then these comments are not copied. I need an xslt statement that copies comments which are present
after the root tag ends 
Below is a code that explains the following

**Original XML**

```
    <Company>
      <Employee id="100" Name="John" >
        <Salary value="15000"/>
        <Qualification text="Engineering">
        <State name="Kerala" code="02">
        <Background text="Indian">
      </Employee>
    </Company>

<!--This file contains Employee information-->
<!--Please refer the file to get information about an employee-->
```

**XSLT Transformation code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Qualification"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Salary" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Background"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output Obtained**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
    <Qualification text="Engineering" />
    <Salary value="15000" />
    <Background text="Indian" />
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

**Output Required**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
    <Qualification text="Engineering" />
    <Salary value="15000" />
    <Background text="Indian" />
   </Employee>
</Company>

<!--This file contains Employee information-->
<!--Please refer the file to get information about an employee-->
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your transformation.  I ran the same XSLT over the same XML (corrected to make it well-formed) using [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) and I get the correct output including the trailing comments (though they have lost their original indentation and spacing due to the `strip-space` and the `indent="yes"` in the stylesheet)

```
<Company>
  <Employee>
    <Qualification text="Engineering"/>
    <Salary value="15000"/>
    <Background text="Indian"/>
  </Employee>
</Company><!--This file contains Employee information-->
<!--Please refer the file to get information about an employee-->
```

It looks like whatever processor or XML parser you're using (presumably a Microsoft one judging by the `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`) is ignoring comments after the end tag of the document element.

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer, I have tried Saxon 6.5.5 and 9.5 from the command line, using a corrected input as yours is not even well-formed, and the comments after the root element are copied by Saxon. If you still have problems then edit your question providing a well-formed input XML, the exact version of Saxon and the exact way you use it (e.g. command line or with Java code).

Comment: I didn't ask the question I was just stating the results I got in OxygenXml.

Comment: I got this working now.... My xslt was like really big and complicated and to make it simpler I pasted only a part of it here.. But I however did not paste the actual problem... It was this line <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
which was actually the code that was surpressing the comments. I removed this piece of code and got it working.. Thanks everyone...

Comment: @MJC if you're using something based on [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17889488/592139) then the simplest fix is to delete the `<xsl:template match="/">` altogether and change the `<xsl:template match="*">` to be `<xsl:template match="/|*">` instead (i.e. apply the same logic to the document root node as we apply to element nodes).  If you just delete the existing root template but don't edit the `*` one then yes, you will pick up comments _after_ the root, but you'll also find that comments _before_ the root appear twice.

Comment: @Ian.. Yes your absolutely right!!... I had noticed the doubling comments before the root node and  taken care of it almost the same way as you have suggested in your comment. Anyways many thanks for all the advices.